# a vector space $V$ over $F$ may be considered as an $F[X]$-module

Tags: vector-spaces, modules

I got stuck on some trivial axiom-checking while reading through my lecture notes; any help would be appreciated.

The following is from my notes:

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $\alpha$ an endomorphism of $V$ (a linear map $V \rightarrow V$).

We consider $V$ as an $F[X]$ module via

$F[X] \times V \rightarrow V$

$(f, v) \mapsto f(\alpha)(v)$

**My question is**: How does this make $V$ into an $F[X]$-module?

We have, $\forall f,g\in F[X], \forall v,w \in V$,

$(f+g)\cdot v := (f+g)(\alpha)(v) = f(\alpha)(v) + g(\alpha)(v) := f\cdot v + g \cdot v$ ($\checkmark$)

$f\cdot (v+w) = f(\alpha)(v+w) = f(\alpha (v) + \alpha(w))$ since $\alpha$ is an endomorphism.

However, I can't see why this last expression should equal $f\cdot v + f\cdot w$, since $f $ is just a polynomial and isn't necessarily linear.

Comment: The last expression $f(\alpha(v)+\alpha(w))$ does not mean anything. However, the previous one $f(\alpha)(v+w)=f(\alpha)(v)+f(\alpha)(w)=f\cdot v+f\cdot w$ because $f(\alpha)$ is also an endomorphism.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh of course! Thanks a lot, I got it now.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily linear, but $f(\alpha)$ is.